# How to redirect all requests to a PHP file inside a subdirectory in apache2?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My document root is `/var/www/html/`.

I created a directory called myapi inside like `/var/www/html/myapi`.

The folder structure in `/var/www/html/myapi` is like

```sh
.
|-- .htaccess
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- src
|   |-- config
|   |-- index.php
`-- vendor
```

I want all the requests such as `http:localhost/myapi/books` would be redirected to the index.php inside the src folder.

my current `.htaccess` setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.svg|\.js)$
RewriteRule (.*) src/index.php [QSA,L]
```

RewriteEngine is already switched on.
But it doesn't work and the server does not respond.

May I know how?

**EDIT: FIXED. I mess up some volume mount for the .htaccess file in docker container.**

Comment: "server does not respond" - what do you mean exactly by that? Otherwise, your `.htaccess` looks "OK" (it could be improved, but should not result in complete failure).

Comment: @MrWhite, I try to send a request with insomnia and it get `Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)`

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem with the rule you've posted. You should at least get a response of some kind (an 5xx "error" response - if there is an error). If you remove your `.htaccess` file entirely what happens?

Comment: Are you sure you've not for a redirect loop going on? Normally you'd put `!-f` (not file) and `!-d` (not directory) `RewriteCond` rules in place rather than just specific file extensions...

Comment: @MrWhite, Thanks for you comment. It turns out I mess some volume mount in docker container for the .htaccess. However, may I know how my `.htaccess` could be improved?

Comment: @CD001, Thanks for your comment. It is because I have some .js and .jpeg file need to be accessed by the client as I also use the same directory for the swagger UI page. Or you have a better idea?

Comment: @CD001 The `!-f` and `!-d` filesystem checks are often used too much. It is always preferable to use a regex/string comparison instead (or as well as) if possible. (The directory check is rarely necessary, unless of course you need direct access to directories.) There is, however, still an unnecessary "loop" here as the request is rewritten to `src/index.php` twice (`src/index.php` is rewritten to itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.svg|\.js)$
> RewriteRule (.*) src/index.php [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> ...may I know how my .htaccess could be improved?

As I mentioned in comments, this is "OK" but can be improved.

This rule unnecessarily rewrites to itself. There is no rewrite-loop here since you are rewriting to a static file-path. (But include a slash prefix on the *substitution* string and you get a rewrite-loop - 500 internal server error.)

There is no need to capture the entire URL-path (ie. `(.*)`), since its not being used.

The *condition* that checks that the request does not end in a known file extension can be moved to the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. (The `RewriteCond` directive is not required.) Remove the dot from the regex alternation to "simplify" the regex. Consider adding `.php` to the list of known file extensions, and/or use the `END` flag (Apache 2.4) instead of `L` to prevent further loops by the rewrite engine.

The `QSA` flag is not required since you are not appending a query string on the *substitution* string. The query string is passed through by default.

For example, use the following instead:

```
RewriteRule !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|zip|css|svg|js)$ src/index.php [END]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really make things complicated. Your answer make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use this following code in .htaccess. I expect it should be work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.svg|\.js)$
RewriteRule (.*) src/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: How is this expected to resolve the issue? It certainly wouldn't "fix" the response the OP appears to be getting. The OP makes no mention of requiring a URL parameter?